# Answering with "Let's!" or "Let's go!"

Tags: grammaticality

I have been reading conversations like the following:

> Person 1: Hey, let's go for a jog this afternoon!
>   
> Person 2: Let's!

Is it correct to only say "Let's!" instead of "Let's go!"?

Comment: instead of repeating "go", a person can say Let's for short.

Comment: @thanhtran what if the question is "Do you want to have lunch with me?" and the reply is "Let's."

Is it correct?

Comment: @patrickeatworld I use that expression regularly, though it may be seen as somewhat pompous ;)

Comment: @msanford haha i need to get used to it!

Comment: @patrickeatworld I would add that if I do use that expression, I almost *never* use it in isolation, but rather say "Yes, let's!" (or some equivalent).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes.**

Answers to questions often omit words which would be repeated from the question:

> “Did you do the dishes?”  “Yes, I did *[do the dishes]*.”

The response “Let’s!” is a grammatically quite standard example of this, and it can mean other things beside “Let’s go”:

> “Do you want to see a film tonight?”  “Yes, let’s *[see a film tonight]*.”

Depending on where you live and whom you talk to, though, “Let’s!” on its own may be more or less idiomatic than “Let’s go!” or other similar answers.  To my ear, “Let’s!” alone seems a bit unusually curt; but “Yes, let’s!” or “Do let’s.” are both quite normal (the latter being perhaps more old-fashioned and more BrE).

Answer (score 5):

It's a common enough expression, but more likely, I'd have thought, to occur as *Yeh, let's.*

Answer (score 4):

*Let's* being a contraction for *let us*, responding "Let's!" to the suggestion to jog is properly informal and conversational.

(Responding with "Let us!" sounds like you're asking permission.)

There's nothing wrong with answering "Let's go!" but it's not necessary, unless Person 2 perhaps wishes to imply "Right now!"

Comment: Ah yes, I agree that responding with "Let us!" sounds like I am asking permission. I guess I am just not used to hearing people responding a question with only "Let's!".

Answer (score 0):

While it might be informal, grammatical and quite common, it’s a rather vague and sloppy way to answer a question. It wouldn’t kill you to add a word or two and say “Let’s go” or “Let’s do it”. In short, “Let’s” is certainly not proper English and you might get a few strange looks if you use it amongst educated or posh people. If you and your friends speak colloquial or “thug”-like English then you can get away with saying it.